# get returned values from jquery get?

Tags: jquery, get

I am making jquery calls to get and getJSON, but cannot access returned values outside of callback function. How can I access the returned data?

```
        var firstid;
        var nextid;

    $.get(callUrl, function(data) {  // call to add node
         var n = data.indexOf("id-");
         var m = data.indexOf("id-");
         firstid = data.substr(n+3,m - (n+3));
         nextid = data.substr(m+3);

             alert("firstid:" + firstid);  // returns correct value
    });

        alert("firstid:" + firstid);  // returns undefined for firstid
```

how can I get firstid outside the function?

Comment: Any [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11156895/144665) help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**ALL AJAX CALLS ARE ASYNCHRONOUS**

SO you **need** to use callbacks. anything outside that will return `undefined`.

```
$.get(callUrl, function(data) {  // call to add node
     var n = data.indexOf("id-");
     var m = data.indexOf("id-");
     firstid = data.substr(n+3,m - (n+3));
     nextid = data.substr(m+3);

     doSomethingWithFirst(firstid);
});

function doSomethingWithFirst(f)   {
     //NOW do something
}
```

Comment: -1 Technically not true. If he wrapped the second `alert("firstid:" + firstid);` in a timeout with a 5 second delay it would display the expected result outside that success function.

Comment: @iambriansreed 5 second delay??? How do you know long the server will take to respond???

Comment: I don't know for sure how long the server may take to respond, you are right, but the argument remains the same:  anything outside that get callback aren't necessarily undefined. The OP was correct to define the variables outside the `get` callback scope and because of that it is updated and later calls to that variable do in fact give the expected results. Finally not ***all*** AJAX calls are asynchronous, you can in fact set the request to synchronous but it is **not recommended**.

Comment: adding arbitrary variables to the global scope is also not recommended... so defining them and passing them would be prudent here (assuming they are not used somewhere else... this example is limited)

Comment: @rlemon I wouldn't be leaving massive answers and comments unless the OP hadn't asked "how can I get firstid outside the function?".

Comment: @iambriansreed it's surely because he does not understand the asynchronous behavior and the fact he has to work with callbacks. Sometimes you don't just have to "give one answer that fit" but you have to explain OP that he does not understand a behavior and *guide/help* him to learn

Comment: @DieVarDump I suppose you haven't [read my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11156895/144665). If you think it may guide/help the OP to learn feel free to up vote.

Comment: how do I set the request to synchronous?

Comment: @user840930 **Do not do that** it will slow down your web app.

Comment: @user840930 **Do not do that** it will slow down your web app and might even crash older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

The second `alert("firstid:" + firstid);` returns `undefined` because at the moment of execution it is in fact `undefined`.

The first `alert("firstid:" + firstid);` returns the expected result as it fires after the `$.get` is finished getting.

**AJAX** - Stands for Asynchronous JavaScript and XML. Asynchronous events are those occurring independently of the main program flow. While you *can* set the request to synchronous it is **not recommended**.

If you wrapped your second `alert("firstid:" + firstid);` in a timeout with a 5 second delay it would display the expected result.

```
setTimeout(function() { alert("firstid:" + firstid); }, 5000);
```

Or you could wrap your second `alert("firstid:" + firstid);` in an interval with a 1 second delay it would eventually display the expected result.

```
var callback_interval = setInterval(function() {
    if(typeof(firstid) == 'undefined') return;
    clearInterval(callback_interval);
    alert("firstid:" + firstid);
}, 1000);
```

But it's best to work with the variables directly in the `$.get` success callback or via function calls within that success callback.

Answer (score 0):

This is because it is done asynchronous (one of the basic principles of AJAX). You can set [async](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to false or use some other callback construction to use your value returned from the get call.